# error. org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, apache, import

I m trying to do a registration page from an android activity connectiong the datas to my sqldatabase, I m getting this error " org.json.JSONException: Value

I know I have seen all similar questions on SO. I tired to solve this error for past 7 hours. i tried almost everything, searched on web and SO a lot, but couldn't get the solution for this error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

****JSONParser.java****

```
public class JSONParser {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){


            Log.d("my", "method equals POST is working");
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            Log.d("my", "HTTp client is working");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.d("my", "HTTp post is working");

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            Log.d("my", "url encoded");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            Log.d("my", "HTTp response is working");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            Log.d("my", "HTTp entity is working");

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.d("my", "getcontent is working");


        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        Log.d("my", "buffer reader crated");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


        Log.d("my", "string buffer object crated");
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

            Log.d("my", "line appended");
        }
        is.close();
        Log.d("my", "inputstram closed");

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d("my", "string buffer to string conversion");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {


        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

TAP_Cliente_nuevo.java

`enter code here`public class Tap_Cliente_Nuevo extends Activity {

```
JSONParser parseadorJson = new  JSONParser();
Button btn;
EditText RFC;
EditText Nombre;
EditText ApellidoP;
EditText ApellidoM;
EditText Telefono;
EditText Calle;
EditText Numero;
EditText Colonia;
EditText Municipio;
EditText Estado;
EditText CP;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tap__cliente__nuevo);
    RFC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRFCCliente);
    Nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNombreCliente);
    ApellidoP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtApellidoPCliente);
    ApellidoM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtApellidoMCliente);
    Telefono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTelefonoCliente);
    Calle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCalleCliente);
    Numero = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroCliente);
    Colonia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtColoniaCliente);
    Municipio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMunicipioCliente);
    Estado = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEstadoCliente);
    CP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCPCliente);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarCliente);       
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(RFC.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Nombre.getText().length()==0 ||
                    ApellidoP.getText().length()==0 ||
                    ApellidoM.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Telefono.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Calle.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Numero.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Colonia.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Municipio.getText().length()==0 ||
                    Estado.getText().length()==0 ||
                    CP.getText().length()==0){                  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor llena los campos obligatorios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            List<NameValuePair> parametros = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inRFC", RFC.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inNombre", Nombre.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inApPat", ApellidoP.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inApMat", ApellidoM.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inTel", Telefono.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inCalle", Calle.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inNum", Numero.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inCol", Colonia.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inMuni", Municipio.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inEsta", Estado.getText().toString()));
            parametros.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inCP", CP.getText().toString()));


          Log.e("Registro", obtenIpServidor());

          parseadorJson.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.72/tractofer/alta_clientes.php", "POST", parametros);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Insertados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RFC.setText("");
            Nombre.setText("");
            ApellidoP.setText("");
            ApellidoM.setText("");
            Telefono.setText("");
            Calle.setText("");
            Numero.setText("");
            Colonia.setText("");
            Municipio.setText("");
            Estado.setText("");
            CP.setText("");
        }

        }
    });
}
public String obtenIpServidor()
{
    String ip=null;

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.tractopartesycamiones_preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.e("Registro",  "tipo_conexion: " + pref.getString("tipo_conexion", "1"));

    if (pref.getString("tipo_conexion", "1").equals( "1"))
        ip="192.168.1.72";
    else
        ip = pref.getString("ip_servidor", "0.0.0.0");


    return ip;
}
```

}

alta_cliente.php

```
<?php
//Constantes

$db_usuario = "root";
$db_pass    = "";
$db_host    = "localhost";
$db_schema  = "tractofer";

//Conexion con la base de datos
$enlace = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_pass)
    or die (' No se conecto al servidor');

mysql_select_db($db_schema,$enlace)
    or die('Error al seleccionar la base de datos');

$respuesta = array();
    $RFC = $_POST['inRFC'];
    $Nombre = $_POST['inNombre'];
    $ApPat = $_POST['inApPat'];
    $ApMat = $_POST['inApMat'];
    $Tel = $_POST['inTel'];
    $Calle = $_POST['inCalle'];
    $Num = $_POST['inNum'];
    $Col = $_POST['inCol'];
    $Muni = $_POST['inMuni'];
    $Esta = $_POST['inEsta'];
    $CP = $_POST['inCP'];

$db_query =
  "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES('$RFC', '$Nombre', '$ApPat', '$ApMat', '$Tel', '$Calle', '$Num', '$Col', '$Muni', '$Esta', '$CP')";
//Ejecutamos el Query
$resultado = mysql_query($db_query,$enlace)
    or die('Error en el query: ' .$db_query);

if($resultado)
{
$respuesta["success"]=1;
$respuesta["message"]="Usuario agregado";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}   
else
{ echo 'Error en el json'; }
//desconexion de la base de datos
@mysql_close($enlace);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `PHP` file you are using `echo` statements, which also outputted as response. So your `json` String contained a html tags and/or lines and because of that it couldn't be parsed.

Or in your `json` String somewhere it contains a `<br />` tag so it can't be parsed.